# Nested function inside While loop - PHP

Tags: php

I have the below code that I am trying to fix. In this code, I have created a class and that has a function testcal() in it. In that function, I connect to database, do a select query from a table. For the result set, I want to loop through and grab values of fields $field1,2,3. Using those fields I am creating another function to throw out the result.

```
<?php
class test
{
    public function testcal()
    {
         set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr){
            error_reporting(0);
        }, E_WARNING);
                
        //database credentials
        $host = "localhost";
        $db_name = "mydb";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
         
        //connect to database
        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
        
        //Query to generate check-in variables from ffc_contrast
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

        //Store result on $result variable
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            
            //assign values to each variable
            $field1 = $row["field1"];
            $field2 = $row["field2"];
            $field3 = 0.5;
            
            ////////////////
            //Calculations//
            ////////////////
            
            function ratingcheck($field1,$field2){
                if($field1 == 0 || $field2 == 0){
                    return 0;
                } elseif ($field1 == 1) {
                    return 1;
                } elseif ($field2 == 2) {
                    return 2;
                }else{
                    return null;
                }
                }
        }
    }   
} 

$test = new test();
print $test->testcal();
?>
```

I am getting an error saying `Cannot redeclare ratingcheck() (previously declared in ~/myfile.php:51) in ~/myfile.php on line 37` I have declared the method correctly and have called the parent method. Not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone help?

Comment: It's inside the while loop, so you redeclare it every time

Comment: Yeah, I want that function to be inside while loop. Thinking if there is a way to do if exists kind of logic..

Comment: yeah, you need to call it inside the loop not define it

Comment: I'm new to PHP, can you pls drop an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class test
{
    public function testcal()
    {
        ....all your code....

        //Store result on $result variable
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $returnValues = [];//not sure what you want here really, as you're returning inside youe while loop
        //so that will only do 1 iteration anyway, so i'm assuming you want to build an array or something
        
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            //assign values to each variable
            $field1 = $row["field1"];
            $field2 = $row["field2"];
            $field3 = 0.5;


            //store the result from the function
            $returnValues[] = $this->ratingcheck($field1,$field2);

        }

        return $returnValues;
    }
    ////////////////
    //Calculations//
    ////////////////
    
    //declare the function once as part of the class, now you can call it
    //i've put private here as it's making an inernal calculation, make it public if you prefer
    private function ratingcheck($field1,$field2){
        if($field1 == 0 || $field2 == 0){
            return 0;
        } elseif ($field1 == 1) {
            return 1;
        } elseif ($field2 == 2) {
            return 2;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}

$test = new test();
print $test->testcal();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked :)

Comment: Incidentally, your variable `$field3` is seemingly redundant

Comment: yeah, sorry that's part of my logic for something else. thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the function `ratingcheck` on every iteration of the while loop. You cannot redeclare functions.

You need to move the function outside the loop and then call it from inside the loop.